# Phalcon on PHP7?

Tags: php, phalcon, php-7

Is PhalconPHP 2.0.10 extension supports PHP 7?

I'm planning to start learning Phalcon and I want to run it in PHP 7. I can't find an article or a blog that says Phalcon can run on PHP 7.

Comment: Why don't you download a sample code and run it yourself to test it?

Comment: here - http://phalcon.io/phalconphp-and-php7

Comment: to_Manikiran: Sorry cant do that Im just starting to learn Phalcon probably I can do that once I got the hang of it... to_Vincent: Brilliant!!! Thanks buddy.

Comment: Phalcon for PHP7 is in build in process. It is not clear when will be ready, but will be. So...for now, try with some of lower versions.
Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upcoming version Phalcon 2.1 (as of writing is RC1) will have beta PHP7 compatibility

> Phalcon 2.1.x has beta PHP7 support, we expect to fix any blocking bug in the next two weeks before the final release. You can try Phalcon running on PHP7 by compiling from the 2.1.x branch using Zephir:

```
git clone http://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon
cd cphalcon
git checkout 2.1.x
zephir build --backend=ZendEngine3
```

Reference: https://blog.phalconphp.com/

---

**UPDATE**

Due to the many changes in Phalcon 2.1, this version won't be backwards compatible with older versions. Therefor the Phalcon development team decided to skip version 2.1 and continue on 3.0.

And of course Phalcon **3.0** is now **PHP7 compatible**.

Answer (score 2):

There are many bugs in phalcon with php7. You shouldn't use it in production.

Still phalcon even with php 5.x is fastest php framework possible.

2.1.x version is partially supporting it, you have to compile it with newest zephir compiler though(master branch)